# Do I need to add an intent-filter when starting a service?

Tags: android, service, intentfilter

I am following a tutorial to [setup a service to start on boot](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/) where the last piece of the code is:

Make an entry of this service in AndroidManifest.xml as

```
<service android:name="MyService">
<intent-filter>
<action
android:name="com.wissen.startatboot.MyService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Now start this service in the BroadcastReceiver MyStartupIntentReceiver’s onReceive method as

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
    serviceIntent.setAction("com.wissen.startatboot.MyService");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);

}
```

As you see it uses intent-filters and when starts the service adds action.
Can I just use

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

What's the advantage of one compared to the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming this is all in one application, you can use the latter form (`MyService.class`).

> What's the advantage of one compared to the other?

I'd use the custom action string if you wanted third parties to start this service.

Answer (score 0):

As I have already mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940334/purpose-of-service-intent-filter-inside-manifest-xml/17940558#comment28576652_17940558), actions may be useful self-testing. E.g., a service performs a lot of tasks. For every task there is an action. If the service is started with an unknown action, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

I usually use this approach in `onStartCommand`.

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (action.equals(ACT_1)) { 
    // Do task #1
} else if (action.equals(ACT_2)) {
    // Do task #2
} else { 
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Illegal action " + action);
}
```