# Will service be called, if application has no activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-manifest

**This IS NOT A DUPLICATE of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307412/android-application-as-a-service-without-activity).**

I either do not clearly understand how serivces work, or it's indeed not what I need. I want the service to process events, must it still be started? If so, why is it implicitly started when activity is defined? I don't want long running operation, I want event handling. As far as I understand, `intent-filter` notifies Android that service should be called, if condition is met, i.e. push message is received. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940334/purpose-of-service-intent-filter-inside-manifest-xml) somewhat confirms the assumption.

When I have an activity in my app service gets fired whenever message arrives:

```
<service android:name=".FbMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But as soon as I comment out the activty in manifest, neither breakpoint is hit nor logcat show any messages. So I assume service is kind of not registerd...
Is activity a MUST?

Comment: @NileshRathod Sure, I've seen this question. But I either do not clearly understand how serivces work, or it's indeed not what I need. I want the service to proccess events, must it still be started? If so, why is it implicitly started when activity is defined? I don't want long running operation, I want event handling. As far as I understand, intent-filer notifiest Android that service should be called if condition is met, i.e. push message is received.

Comment: Why not use `BroadcastReceiver`s?

Comment: @F43nd1r Will have a look at it, thanks. I am new to Android. Still want to anderstand all this stuff with intent-filters.