# Is service started when intent filter is specified?

Tags: android, android-service

In code examples where service is declared with intent filters in manifest I do not see explicit start of the service. It looks like using intent filters is similar to subscription to system events, so I assume service is created by the system itself. However, it’s not clear for me whether service is even started in that case.

Comment: you have to call `Context#startService` no matter if it has intent filters or not

Comment: @pskink But I have service which extends from Firebase messaging service, and nowhere I start it explicitly.

Comment: maybe not directly, but for sure firebase code you are using in your app does call it

Comment: @pskink Ok then, I need to understand that subtlety. The presence of main activity in manifest causes start of the service, but nothing happens, if activity is not defined ...

Comment: i have no idea what you mean honestly....

Comment: @pskink Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574844/will-service-be-called-if-application-has-no-activity).